# Что будет если продавать приложение созданное на Qt без покупки лицензии?

Tags: qt

Код соответственно не будет выложен в открытый доступ.
з.ы продаю как физическое лицо, а не от лица компании. Как они смогут меня засудить, если мои данных не указаны.

Еще такой вопрос, QT предлагает защиту моих приложений если я куплю платную версию, это как вообще работает? т.е к примеру приложения созданные на бесплатной лицензии легко взломать?

Comment: я когда то (4-5 лет назад) пытался понять, как их лицензия работает и не смог. Но компания продавала приложение, написанное на Qt и юристы говорили, что все ок. Лицензию точно никто не покупал.  Если использовать по lgpl лицензии, то свое приложение можно продавать, а библиотеки Qt просто поставлять, не модифицируя и не линковаться статически.

Answer (score 1):

Если приложение собранно динамикой, то можешь продавать по условиям LGPL.

Также можно продавать не приложение, а услуги поддержки.